# What is the eigenvalue perturbation if a row-column pair is changed?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $M \in \mathbb{S}^d_+$ be a $d$-dimensional symmetric positive definite matrix. Any element of $M$ is bounded, i.e., $|M_{ij}|\le \kappa$. I was wondering how the eigenvalues of $M$ change if I symmetrically change one row-column pair of $M$ (i.e., change the $i$-th row and $i$-th column of $M$, and the new matrix $M'$ is still symmetric positive definite).

The [Cauchy's interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem) seems related to my question, but it's about eigenvalue perturbation if a row-column pair is removed.

Comment: How do you change the row-column pair? Fill it with zeros? Ones?

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azeved, just replace this pair with any other vector, but each element of the vector is bounded by $\kappa$

Comment: Would be easier without the symmetry constraint.

Comment: I thought symmetric is a special case, and it would be easier... Any thought for asymmetric case?